# The plot of instantaneous power of the Dirac function

Tags: power-spectral-density, continuous-signals, impulse-response, signal-power, time-domain

I am very confused. I have tried researching this question for the last two weeks and I cannot get a conclusive answer.

I was wondering how would I go about plotting the instantaneous power in the time domain of the Dirac input signal.
The problem becomes as I try to calculate the power in time domain, $P(t) = \left\lvert\delta(t)\right\rvert^2$. I know how to calculate power by using Rayleigh's theorem to convert the the signal to frequency domain where delta(f) = 1. to get infinity over an infinite period which is undefined value for power, but I just want to plot power over time for the Dirac function.

delta isn't square-able since as x goes to 0 the delta function goes to infinity and you cannot square infinity, also something about the delta function being a distribution and not able to be square-able.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to be able to plot this function.

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this? A Dirac impulse is not a function. What could be the possible interpretation or utility of calculating its "power"?

Comment: How are you trying to use the delta functional that you need to calculate its power?  For engineering purposes, the delta functional is there to make your life easier -- if it's making your life impossible, you're misusing it.

Comment: the other thing that you should be aware of is that, while the ***notion*** of White Noise exists, the reality of White Noise does not.  White Noise has equal power per Hz of bandwidth and an unlimited bandwidth.  so White Noise (which has a power spectrum that is flat all the way to infinity and a dirac delta as an autocorrelation) has more power output than the sun.

Comment: @MBaz It's part of an assignment I was asked to plot the instantaneous power of the signal.

Comment: @lowFrequencyLearning Then I suggest asking your instructor to clarify the meaning of the assignment, given what you have learned here.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem becomes as I try to calculate the power in time domain, $P(t) = \left\lvert\delta(t)\right\rvert^2$

As you figured out yourself, that's impossible: the power of the Dirac impulse isn't defined, it diverges (goes to infinity).

Hence, you especially can't plot the power "correctly"; it's zero anywhere but at $t=0$, where it diverges.

But quite honestly, this should come as no surprise: you can't correctly plot $\delta(t)$, either (the value at $t=0$ isn't defined just as much as its square isn't).

So, whatever question can be answered by that plot: I'm afraid you'll have to find a "better" question.

Comment: Would you say the function |δ(t)|^2 could be similar to the plot of the δ(t) function?

Comment: again, none of these have a plot. They are **not** functions. So, "is it similar" can be answered with "what are you even talking about?"

Comment: thanks for replying